# Vectorized way of finding difference between consecutive elements? Maybe a variation of np.diff()?

Tags: numpy, math, statistics

I want to find two type differences of consecutive elements of an array . 
One of them being:

> diff1 = [x1-x0,x2-x1,x3-x2, ... ]

This, I am able to achieve using np.diff() function from the numpy library. However, the other type of difference I want is:

> diff2 = [x0-x1,x1-x2,x2-x3, ....]

I can achieve this using for loop, however, the size of the array is quite large. Is there a vectorized function this?

Also, I am not sure what these difference are called in statistics? or if there is a term for such an operation. Being unsure of what such an operation is called, I am unable to look up on the internet for a solution.

Comment: Take a look at `?diff`

Comment: As thelatemail said, use the `diff` command. Then, `diff2 <- (-diff1)` (parens just for clarity), unless I'm misunderstanding the math.

Comment: You should be able to just do the math. Here is an example using a vector. `x<-((1:100)*rep(c(1,2),50))`
`x`

`diff1<-x[2:length(x)]-x[1:length(x)-1]`
`diff1`


`diff2<-x[1:length(x)-1]-x[2:length(x)]`
`diff2`

Comment: Ahhh, you just removed the [tag:r] tag ... yes, having an incorrect tag can really skew the conversation in the wrong direction. You're looking for a python-only solution for `diff2`?

Comment: Yes, however, these R based solutions are helpful too. I am trying to translate them to python.

Comment: @DevanshiSukhija `diff2` would be simply `-np.diff(a)` or more efficient with `a[:-1]-a[1:]` with `a` being the array.

Comment: @Divkar: You should post this as an answer, since the two existing ones are still related to R.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comment by @Divakar:

> diff2 would be simply -np.diff(a) or more efficient with a[:-1]-a[1:]
>   with a being the array.

was the perfect solution I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for a solution in `r` (as you tag it in your question), you can have the use of `lag`/`lead` function from `dplyr` package.

Here, to illustrate this, I create a fake vector that I transform as a data.frame to be used in `dplyr`, then the function `mutate` create a new column with the corresponding function:

```r
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(A = sample(1:10,10, replace = TRUE))

library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(Diff1 = A-lag(A), Diff2 = A-lead(A))

    A Diff1 Diff2
1   3    NA     0
2   3     0    -7
3  10     7     8
4   2    -8    -4
5   6     4     1
6   5    -1     1
7   4    -1    -2
8   6     2    -3
9   9     3    -1
10 10     1    NA
```

Does it answer your quesiton ?

Answer (score 2):

Using `diff` as suggested by @thelatemail and @r2evans  is straightforward. However, another alternative is using `head` and `tail`

```
diff1 <- tail(x, -1) - head(x, -1)
diff1
#[1]  7 -8  6 -2  3 -8  6 -2 -1

diff2 <- head(x, -1) - tail(x, -1)
diff2
#[1] -7  8 -6  2 -3  8 -6  2  1
```

**data**

```
set.seed(123)
x <- sample(10)
x
#[1]  3 10  2  8  6  9  1  7  5  4
```